# VBA runtime error 3021 - No Current Record

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to export multiple datasets to the respective new Excel file.

```
   Public Sub MultipleQueries()

Dim i As Integer
Dim Mailer As Database
Dim rs1 As Recordset
Dim rs2 As Recordset
Dim qdf As QueryDef

Set Mailer = CurrentDb
Set rs1 = Mailer.OpenRecordset("MailerData")
Set qdf = Mailer.CreateQueryDef("CCspl", "PARAMETERS CostCentre Text ( 255 );SELECT MonthlyFteData.CostCentre, MonthlyFteData.EmpName, MonthlyFteData.Workload FROM MonthlyFteData WHERE (((MonthlyFteData.CostCentre)=[CostCentre]))")

For i = 0 To rs1.RecordCount - 1

qdf.Parameters("CostCentre") = rs1.Fields("CostCentre")

    Dim oExcel As Object
   Dim oBook As Object
   Dim oSheet As Object
   Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
   Set oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

Set rs2 = qdf.OpenRecordset()

With rs2

oSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs2
oBook.SaveAs "C:\Users\807140\Downloads\" & rs2.Fields("CostCentre") & ".xlsx"

rs2.Close
oExcel.Quit
Set oExcel = Nothing

End With

rs1.MoveNext
Next i

qdf.Close
Set qdf = Nothing
rs1.Close

End Sub
```

But I get the Runtime Error 3021 - No Current Record

I substituted the

```
oSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs2
oBook.SaveAs "C:\Users\807140\Downloads\" & rs2.Fields("CostCentre") & ".xlsx"
```

with

```
Debug.Print .RecordCount
```

And I do actually get the appropriate record count for rs2.

How can I fix my code to eliminate the error?

Comment: What's the recordcount for Rs1? Also, just a thought. You shouldn't need to Dim your variables inside the first for loop.

Comment: Recordcount was inside loop and I was getting one for each rs2 loop.
That was the actual amount of records in each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has a few issues pointed out by @Andre and Ryan.

You're not reusing your Excel object, you're re-dimming objects that should only be defined once, using a With that never gets referenced so it just adds to code with no benefit.

You're also creating a parameter query on the fly in code - instead of creating it in SQL and saving it to be reused by name.

You can try this rewritten code and see if it works better for you. I do believe that a predefined query is the better way to go - and then I'd close the query inside the loop and reset it at the start each time. I've just seen weird stuff happen when querydefs are reused inside loops without resetting them.

**Anyways give this a try** - and report on specific line that causes error

```
Public Sub MultipleQueries()

    Dim i       As Integer
    Dim Mailer  As Database
    Dim rs1     As Recordset
    Dim rs2     As Recordset
    Dim qdf     As QueryDef

    Dim oExcel  As Object
    Dim oBook   As Object
    Dim oSheet  As Object

    ' Only Open and Close Excel once
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Set Mailer = CurrentDb
    Set rs1 = Mailer.OpenRecordset("MailerData")

    ' Ideally you'd put this create query ahead of time instead of dynamically
    Set qdf = Mailer.CreateQueryDef("CCspl", "PARAMETERS CostCentre Text ( 255 );SELECT MonthlyFteData.CostCentre, MonthlyFteData.EmpName, MonthlyFteData.Workload FROM MonthlyFteData WHERE (((MonthlyFteData.CostCentre)=[CostCentre]))")

    Do Until rs1.EOF

        ' Sometimes weird things happen when you reuse querydef with new parameters
        qdf.Parameters("CostCentre") = rs1.Fields("CostCentre")
        Set rs2 = qdf.OpenRecordset()

        If Not rs2.EOF Then
            Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
            Set oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

            oSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs2
            oBook.SaveAs "C:\Users\807140\Downloads\" & rs2.Fields("CostCentre") & ".xlsx"
        Else
            Msgbox "No Data Found for: " & rs1.Fields("CostCentre") 
            Exit Do
        End If

        rs2.Close

        Set rs2 = Nothing
        Set oBook = Nothing     
        Set oSheet = Nothing        

        rs1.MoveNext
    Loop

    oExcel.Quit

    qdf.Close
    rs1.Close
    Mailer.Close

    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set rs1 = Nothing
    Set Mailer = Nothing

    ' Remove Excel references
    Set oBook = Nothing
    Set oSheet = Nothing
    Set oExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I would just like to mention that `Do While Not rs1.EOF` is safer than `Do Until rs1.EOF`, because the latter will always enter the loop and access `rs1` fields, even if the recordset is empty.

Comment: @Andre - not whenever I have used it - I use DAO. Is it different in ADO? Here's a test `Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table1 Where 1=2")
    Do Until rs.EOF
        MsgBox "In Loop"
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop`

Comment: Whoa, you're right, sorry. I wrongly assumed that `Do Until x ... Loop` would always enter the loop at least once, but that's only true for `Do ... Loop Until x`.

Comment: Hi,
I used the code and it works great.
Just one little doubt yet: I do not need to set oExcel = Nothing, oExcel.Quit is equivalent?

Comment: No you're right - you should `set oExcel = nothing` at the end - that removes the reference. I'll edit my answer. If this fits your question as an answer make sure to check it as such. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Code worked. Maybe I need to add a line to remove the qdf reference.
I did accept the answer. Not sure it was what you were asking for. it is my first post.
Pls let me know if correct.

Comment: Thanks - looks like you're on your way. Enjoy the coding

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `For..Next` loops with Recordsets. Use this:

```
Do While Not rs1.EOF
    ' do stuff with rs1
    rs1.MoveNext
Loop
rs1.close
```

And as Ryan wrote, `Dim` don't belong into any loop, move them to the start of the sub.

If this doesn't help, please tell us on which line the error occurs.

Comment: Hi, I used teh suggested code below, but thank you for clarifying the technical problem with loops.

Answer (score 2):

The 3021 error (*"No current record."*) occurs at the second of these two lines:

```vb
oSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs2
oBook.SaveAs "C:\Users\807140\Downloads\" & rs2.Fields("CostCentre") & ".xlsx"
```

That happens because the `rs2` recordset pointer is at `EOF` after you do `CopyFromRecordset rs2`.  Then at `SaveAs`, you ask for `rs2.Fields("CostCentre")`, but there is no available record (*"no current record"*) when the recordset pointer is at `EOF`.

However the `rs1.Fields("CostCentre")` value you used as the query parameter when opening `rs2` is still accessible.  So you can make the error go away by asking for `rs1.Fields("CostCentre")` instead of `rs2.Fields("CostCentre")`

```vb
oBook.SaveAs "C:\Users\807140\Downloads\" & rs1.Fields("CostCentre") & ".xlsx"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for suggesting the fix and explaining.